# Expected length of longest increasing subsequence of a random sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ is a random permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $L_n$ is the length of the longest increasing subsequence of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n,$ where a sequence of indices $i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_r$ is said to constitute an increasing subsequence if $X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \ldots, X_{i_r}$ is increasing.

It is known that $c_1\sqrt{n}\leq \mathbb{E}L_n\leq c_2\sqrt{n}$ for some $c_1,c_2>0.$ The lower bound is easy to show using the [Erdös-Szekers theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem). Is there an easy way to show the upper bound?

Comment: Superadditivity of Hammersley's process derived from the planar Poisson representation, as explained in the first pages of [this canonical reference on the subject](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01204214).

Comment: See Lemma 1.4 on p. 9 in Dan Romik's book, which you can download from his homepage: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~romik/book/

Comment: Thanks. This is extremely useful.