Longest Increasing Subsequence Upper Bound
Assume that the sequence $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Now, define the length longest increasing subsequent as $$L_n=\max\{k:X_{i_1}<X_{i_2}<...<X_{i_k}, 1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_k\leq n\}.$$
(1) Show that $\mathbb P[L_n\geq 2e\sqrt{n}]<\exp\{-2e\sqrt{n}\}$
(2) Show that for every $a>\frac{1}{3}$ there exists a constant b such that for all large $n$ we have: $$\mathbb P[|L_n-\mathbb E[L_n]|\geq n^a]\leq\exp\{-n^b\}.$$
My attempt:
(1) It is not difficult to prove that the upper bound is $\mathbb P[L_n\geq k]\leq \begin{pmatrix}n\\ k\end{pmatrix}\cdot\frac{1}{k!}$. However, I cannot connect this bound with the bound given in the question.
(2) Using Azuma's inequality, I can prove that $$\mathbb P[|L_n-\mathbb E[L_n]|\geq t]\leq2\exp\bigg\{-\frac{t^2}{2n}\bigg\}.$$
Again, I don't know how to get rid of the coefficient 2 outside the exponential and also the coefficient 1/2 inside the exponential.
If you have any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can also check some related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622315
And other materials: Romik, Dan. The surprising mathematics of longest increasing subsequences. No. 4. Cambridge University Press, 2015.

For (1), using some classical bounds of binomial coefficients, e.g., Proof for the upper bound and lower bound for binomial coefficients., we get
$$
\binom{n}{k}/k! \leq \frac{n^k}{(\frac{k}{e})^{2k}}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\Pr[L_n \geq 2e\sqrt{n}] \leq \frac{n^k}{(\frac{k}{e})^{2k}}\bigg\rvert_{k = 2e\sqrt{n}} \leq 4^{-k} < \exp(-k).
$$
For (2), can you compute the expectation and use tail bounds?

[+1] Can we exactly determine the distribution of $L_n$?

@Vezen BU      Thank you, can you explain a little bit more how you get the second inequality (I mean how to get $4^{-k}$. Also, for (2), for tail bounds, you refer to what inequality?

For the second inequality, you just put $k = 2e\sqrt{n}$ into the term.
For (2), I believe you can start with Markov and Chebyshev.
